# Run installed package from pexpect

Tags: python, python-3.x, pexpect, pkg-resources

I have downloaded [pyocd](https://github.com/mbedmicro/pyOCD) and built it successfully. Now I am able to run the tool from command line from any location. However when try to run it using pexpect it shows following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\elephant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pyocd-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Projects\runner\mytest\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-39.1.0-py3.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3086, in <module>
  File "C:\Projects\runner\mytest\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-39.1.0-py3.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3070, in _call_aside
  File "C:\Projects\runner\mytest\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-39.1.0-py3.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 3099, in _initialize_master_working_set
  File "C:\Projects\runner\mytest\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-39.1.0-py3.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 574, in _build_master
  File "C:\Projects\runner\mytest\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-39.1.0-py3.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 892, in require
  File "C:\Projects\runner\mytest\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools-39.1.0-py3.7.egg\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 778, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pyocd==0.14.1.dev277+dirty' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Please help to understand what is wrong and why it works from command line?

Comment: It sounds like the `$PYTHONPATH` variable is not set correctly. Or perhaps you installed an inconsistent version? `.dev277+dirty` sounds a bit strange, did you install from a git repository?

Comment: @MartinUeding You are right this was custom build. I have just cloned sources from Git and built it. The behavior is the same, but different version:
`pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pyocd==0.17.1.dev71' distribution was not found and is required by the application`

Comment: @MartinUeding There is no `$PYTHONPATH` variable at all. pyocd executable located in `c:\Users\elephant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts`.

Comment: Version is correct `c:\>pyocd -V` output is `0.17.1.dev71`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I tried to spawn `pyocd.exe` and `pexpect` was not able to find the package.
I changed the line to `python -m pyocd` and it just works fine.
I am new in Python and mistakenly thought that exe is compiled code as the other exe files in Windows. However, it is just an instruction to run the package using Python.